# how to get all subsites by microsoft graph using C#?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to get all subsites in a site, including all subsite levels. I use this way:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/sites
```

but it can only get the first subsite level of the site. How to get all the subsites?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

This will list all the sites and subsites.

Comment: I refer to this article to get all subsites: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508878/get-count-of-all-the-subsites-all-levels-in-all-site-collections-in-sharepoint/59754031#59754031". But I get this error: "Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.". how to fix this problem?   The Connect-SPOService is succesful.

Comment: You need to be a SharePoint Online global administrator and a site collection administrator to run the cmdlet.

Comment: @kapo what you are asking in the comments is a totally different thing from the original question..